# Bootstrap carousel activation with php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, carousel

I can activate the bootstrap carousel.The problem is on the active class. I use $count in the while statement. With code I get active class for all courosel item. But i need to add the active class for every item when the items are slided.

Here is the code--

```html
<?php include "connection.php"; ?>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_slide ORDER BY slide_id DESC LIMIT 4";
$slide_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// $count = mysqli_num_row($slide_query);
$slides = '';
$indicators = '';
$counter = 1;
if (!$slide_query) {
die('Query Failed'. mysqli_query($conn));
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slide_query)){
$slide_id = $row['slide_id'];
$slide_image = $row['slide_image'];
$slide_content = $row['slide_content']; 
if($counter == 1){
$indicators .= '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="'.$counter.'" class="active"></li>';
$slides .='<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/slideImage/'.$slide_image.'"</div>';
}else{
$indicators .= '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="'.$counter.'"></li>';
$slides .='<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/slideImage/'.$slide_image.'"</div>';

}
$counter ++;}?>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide my-4" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<?php echo $indicators; ?>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<?php echo $slides;?>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not make something to slide with php and MySQL alone, All you need to do is get all of the slides from database and append them to your HTML and with Javascript make them to slide

this is the example of [W3Schools for BS Carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp)

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

you should get all of your slide from database and append them to ol section,

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
```

for the indicators and for the image and captions append data like this

```
<div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```